# Did the New York Times really testify to the eternity of the Jewish People?

Tags: shabbat, candle-lighting, publications

There's a story I've heard quite a few times that is reprinted all over Jewish sites on the internet. It goes like this:

*On January 1, 2000, the NY Times ran a Millennium edition. It was a special issue that featured three front pages. One had the news from January 1, 1900. The second was the actual news of the day, January 1, 2000. And then they had a third front page, projecting future events of January 1, 2100.
This fictional page included things like a welcome to the fifty-first state: Cuba, as well as a discussion as to whether robots should be allowed to vote. And so on.
And in addition to the fascinating articles, there was one more thing. Down on the bottom of the Year 2100 front page was the candle lighting time in New York for January 1, 2100. Nobody paid for it. It was just put in by the Times.
When the production manager of the New York Times – an Irish Catholic – was asked about it, his answer was right on the mark. And it speaks to the eternity of our people. And to the power of the Jewish tradition and its women.
The production manager explained: “We don’t know what will happen in the year 2100. It is impossible to predict the future. But of one thing you can be certain, that in the year 2100 Jewish women will be lighting Shabbos candles."*

I've tried to find some evidence of this. I looked for a NYT Millennium edition and couldn't. Does anyone know if this actually happened or if it's an urban legend?

Comment: As background information for this question, it is worth noting (perhaps [edit]ed into the question) that there had, for years, been a small ad at the bottom of the front page of _The New York Times_ every Friday advertising the time to light candles in New York.

Comment: I think it belongs on Skeptics.SE

Comment: This question is about a statement made about a practice of Judaism and as such is completely within this site's scope (i.e. is on-topic) and should be reopened.

Comment: I agree with @msh210 that this falls within our scope.  (It might also be on-topic on History.  To ask on Skeptics you'd need to cite a notable claim.)

Comment: @msh210 What does this have to do with practice of Judaism? That we will have to light candles in 2100?

Comment: @MonicaCellio It's a question if 1. a NYTimes article exists and 2. if a manager said something about Jews.

Comment: @ShmuelBrin, it's a question as to (1) whether a _NYT_ fake-ad **about Judaism** exists and I don't think the production manager thing is part of the question, but, if it is, (2) whether he said something **about Judaism**.

Comment: @msh210 "Questions about comparative religion, and questions about **what others have written about Judaism**, are off-topic on Mi Yodeya." Might be a more appropriate close reason.

Comment: @Scimonster, good point. But this is more on-topic since what the others wrote about Judaism is a take-off of what Jews wrote (for Judaism-related purposes) about Judaism. In other words, the "Judaism" part isn't candlelighting but the real ads, and the question is about the spoof ad, which is so similar to the real one that I think this shouldn't count as a "what others have written about Judaism" question. I agree it's debatable, but I still think it should be reopened.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

[This microfilm copy](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2aLNBKlglgELW1maFMzUlFVOTQ/view?pli=1) of the *New York Times* special millennium edition (dated January 1, 2100, actually published January 1, 2000) shows the Shabbat candle lighting times entry that you refer to.  It is found in the lower left corner.  The actual text of it says:

> JEWISH WOMEN/GIRLS LIGHT SHABBAT
>   candles today 18 minutes before
>   sunset In New York
>   4:39 PM  Elsewhere touch [?] for local time and for
>   information — ADVT

[image: clip of newspaper quoted in full above]

Answer (score 2):

I have seen it with my own eyes a few years ago. Although that doesn't make sense since your reference says it was printed in 2000. But i remember seeing it in the past 6 or so years.